# Reading a website table from android

Tags: android

I would like to read a 3 column table from a site and store it to three variables `col1`,`col2`,`col3`
I found here a sample code
[connecting to the web tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/39810/1954)
and I'm trying to manipulate it

```
String str = DownloadText("http://XXXX.com/table1.htm");
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setText(str);
```

know i see on the emulator the html source

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<body>

<table border="0">
<tr>
<td class="col1">8800</td>
<td class="col2">test</td>
<td class="col3">300</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I store each cell into a variable (e.g. col1=8000, col2=test, col3=300) ?

Answer (score 1):

try to use 
i am not sure but may help you

```
String str = DownloadText("http://XXXX.com/table1.htm");
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `BufferedReader` it lets you read a string line by line. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html . For instance:

```
   private void readHtml(String htmlString) {

       StringReader reader = new StringReader(htmlString);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        try {

            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();    

            while(line != null) {

             if(line.contains("<td>") && line.contains("</td>")) {
               String yourData = line.replaceAll("<td>", "").replaceAll("</td>", "");
               //Do something with it

             }

             line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            }


            bufferedReader.close();

        }

        catch(IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement the code but I got errors, I add class to the html source to help identify it,could you make a private function from it ?

Comment: Edited. You can just copy&paste the function to your code. You got errors because I didn't add try/catch.